# Android: Location access authorization change event?

Tags: android, xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin Android and I want to trigger an event whenever the location access is changed by a user. When the app starts it prompts for permission to access location service, I want to trigger some event when a user selects yes or no. Are there any such events in Android that can handle it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `PermissionChecker` class's `CheckSelfPermission(string permission)` method which was introduced in API 23.0 
Eg code:

```
const string permission = Manifest.Permission.AccessFineLocation; //Also you can use ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION
if (CheckSelfPermission(permission) == (int)Permission.Granted)
{
    //Operation if permission is granted
}
else
{
    //Operation if permission is not granted
}
```

Further reading https://blog.xamarin.com/requesting-runtime-permissions-in-android-marshmallow/